# Cordova File Plugin: Write/Read written files after app is reinstalled (android)

Tags: typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-file

So I have been trying to save offline data to an external directory (Documents in this case),
to be able to restore data after app is reinstalled.

Writing/Reading behaves correctly until the app is reinstalled, the filereader results always yields `null`

My file writing code:

```
resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, (fs) => {
    fs.getFile('Documents/mydata.txt', { create: true },  (fileEntry) => {
        fileEntry.createWriter((fileWriter) => {
            fileWriter.write(new Blob(['some data', 'text/plain']));
        });
    }, e => {
        console.log(e);
        // yeilds {code: 1}
    });
})
```

My file reading code:

```
resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, (fs) => {
    fs.getFile('Documents/mydata.txt', {},  (fileEntry) => {
        fileEntry.file((file) => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            
            reader.onloadend = () => {
                console.log(reader.result, reader.error);
                // yeilds null, { code: 1 }
            }

            reader.readAsText(file);

        });
    });
})
```

Thanks

Comment: is this behavior on android or ios?